# Point string to php page and query

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've been trying the past 2-3 hours to get this working but I simply don't have enough knowledge of regex.

I'm trying to make an url shortener, so I want to point a url like `domain.com/d5Ds93X` to something like `domain.com/view.php?s=d5Ds93X`

I've been messing around with my .htaccess file and have this now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /(.*?)$ /view.php?s=$1 [L]
```

And that sort of works, it points to the right file but the string (d5Ds93X) isn't passed on. My `view.php` file looks like this (for testing purposes):

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['s']) && ctype_alnum($_GET['s'])) {
        echo $_GET['s'];
    }
?>
```

When visiting the url I just get a blank page. But if I echo anything before the `if` rule it does get displayed so the page works just fine. Does the data of the GET even get passed on? Or should I add code that detects the data in the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ view.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make leading slash optional so that rule works from .htaccess as well as from Apache config.

Also restrict rule to skip files and directories.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a load! Works perfectly. Any chance you could explain what each part of `^/?(.+)$` means? And I'm guessing it I want /admin/ to redirect to a different page I just put that rewrite rule before it with an [L] to prevent is from looking at other rules right?

Comment: `^/?` make `/` optional at the start. `(.+)` matches 1 or more of any characters and finally `$` is for end of input.

Comment: @s1h4d0w Please if the answer solves your problem accept it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll mark your answer as soon as I can, stackoverflow tells me I need to wait a few minutes before I can accept it.